# Parsing multiple XML tags in groovy and inserting into Oracle db

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have a requirement of reading multiple tags in an XML recursively. I have written this code in ODI in Groovy, which does not give any errors but also does not give any output.  It is supposed to insert 2 rows into my db looking at the xml, but it does no inserts. Seems like a problem with the hierarchy of tags. Please help me out here.

xml file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbKBU.png)

groovy code:

```
 File SFDCResponseFile = new File("/drxe2o/admin/Integration/odi/reference_data/sfdc/copy_center/Sample.xml")
        if (!SFDCResponseFile?.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No SFDC Query Response file ${SFDCResponseFile.absolutePath}")
        }

   def myCon = odiRef.getJDBCConnection("SRC")
   def myStmt = myCon.createStatement()

    def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parse(SFDCResponseFile)

slurper.queryResponse.result.records.each
{
            myStmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO <%=odiRef.getSchemaNameDefaultPSchema("LS_ODI_WORK","D")%>.RX_ODI_TAGVALUE_TEMP " +
                "(EVENT_CODE,EVENT_EDITION,ORDER_SUMMARY_NUMBER) " +
                "VALUES ('${it.Event_Code__c.text()}','${it.Event_Edition__c.text()}','${it.Order_Summary_Number__c.text()}')")
}
```

Comment: Have you check the query string is correct..? Because It looks like you may missed to escape from double quotes and xml file instead of image.

Comment: Could you provide the content of the `Sample.xml` file?